# Por que multiplicação é mais rápido que divisão?

Tags: javascript, matemática, desempenho, otimização, característica-linguagem

Pergunta de escovação de bit, mas estava eu lendo um artigo sobre javascript em que diz que divisão é mais lenta que fazer multiplicações.

E por exemplo, recomendava mudar o código abaixo :

```
var resultado = 4/2;
```

por esse que seria mais rápido.

```
var resultado = 4 * .5;
```

Isso acontece em qualquer linguagem? E por que multiplicar é mais performático que dividir?

Eis o link do artigo (em inglês) que mencionei, na seção **Math** : http://jessefreeman.com/game-dev/intro-to-programming-for-games-with-javascript/

Comment: Fiz o teste no console e não reparei diferença alguma

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Creio que seja perceptível se a execução do código precisa ser repetido inúmeras vezes.

Comment: Criei um teste de performance em JavaScript: http://jsperf.com/multiply-vs-divide-fight de vez em quando a divisão se mostra mais rápida, então se houver mesmo alguma diferença em Javascript, deve ser insignificante.

Comment: Agora a ironia: a divisão parece ser consistentemente mais rápida do que a multiplicação no Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: estou usando chrome e no teste do jsperf a divisão foi mais rápida... não creio que essa questão seja pertinente em js

Comment: A meu ver, uma boa resposta precisa contemplar o seguinte: 1) em hardware, divisão (iterativa) é inerentemente mais lenta do que multiplicação (paralela); 2) mesmo com divisão tendo mais latência em hardware do que multiplicação, qual o impacto da vazão dessas operações; 3) operações com constantes são otimizadas por compiladores modernos. O mesmo ocorre em motores de JavaScript? Se sim, uma discussão do estado-da-arte; 4) melhorar os testes de avaliação: os listados aqui aparentam ser inconclusivos, seja por uso de constantes ou por não (des)considerar a sobrecarga administrativa dos testes.

Comment: Faça a conta na mão. Divisão dá mais trabalho que multiplicação, certo? Para o processador também :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, isso vale para todas as linguagens, afinal a operação se dá no processador. E se o processador não possui a função de divisão, esta precisa ser emulada utilizando outras operações. Segue explicação:

Na multiplicação, para cada posição, você está multiplicando apenas por 0 ou 1, o que é realmente fácil de fazer: você quer obter todos os zeros, ou você recebe a entrada original de volta.
Como resultado, cada bit parcial do produto pode ser calculado com uma porta **AND**.
Depois de ter todos os produtos parciais, basta adicioná-los em conjunto. Há algumas otimizações que você pode fazer para acelerar a lógica, mas de qualquer forma você pode ver que este processo pode ser feito de forma muito rápida.

A divisão, por outro lado, é tão feia em binário quanto é em decimal.
Algoritmos mais simples são feitos da mesma forma que era na escola: O velho algoritmo de *"palpitar e corrigir, se necessário"* , enquanto isso, algoritmos mais rápidos tendem a usar tabelas de pesquisa *(que ocupam área de chip, portanto gastam mais)*.

---

**Wikipedia sobre algoritmos de divisão:** Nota-se que mesmo os algoritmos rápidos ainda são interativos - enquanto a multiplicação pode ser feita de uma só vez, a divisão exige a interações repetidas.

[Fonte](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=81793)

Comment: Isso pra mim não faz muito sentido, pois qualquer divisão é simplesmente uma multiplicação pelo inverso do quociente. Ainda assim, as fontes estão me ajudando a entender o assunto, então +1.

Comment: O algoritmo de divisão possui a mesma ordem do da multiplicação. Quando puder vou exemplificar os algoritmos.

Comment: @Renan Exato. Mas mesmo pensando dessa forma, serão dois trabalhos contra um só: `1- inverter o número; 2- multiplicar.` Contra apenas multiplicar. Muitos compiladores hoje em dia são inteligentes o suficientes pra inverter constantes em compile-time, isso é, `var /= 2` vai virar `var *= 0.5` mais hora menos hora na compilação. Mas quando lidando com variáveis não-constantes, vale o bom senso de performance vs usabilidade.

Comment: Segundo [a Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm), existe uma forma de reduzir uma divisão para uma multiplicação e um shift: para dividir por `D`, em vez de multiplicar por `1/D` escolha `M` e `N` bem grandes tal que `M/N == 1/D`. Então, substitua `N` por `N'` tal que `N'` é uma potência de dois (daí dividir vira somente um shift) e a diferença entre `M/N` e `M/N'` seja **menor que a margem de erro** nas operações em ponto flutuante (i.e. os resultados sejam iguais). Só não sei se isso é comumente aplicado na prática (e se o é, se é em geral ou só pra constantes).

Comment: Obs.: Iterativo (iterative) = onde é necessário iterar, isto é, fazer loop. Interativo (interactive) = onde é possível interagir, isto é, há ação entre o usuário e o computador.

Answer (score 14):

## Testes realizados

Segundo os resultados do [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/multiply-vs-divide-fight) apresentado pelo Renan, [outros testes que criei diferenciando inteiros e ponto flutuante](http://jsperf.com/multiply-vs-divide-fight/3) e os [testes recentemente criados pelo Marcelo](http://jsperf.com/multiply-vs-divide-fight/4) a afirmação "multiplicação é mais rápido que divisão em Javascript" não é *sempre* verdadeira.

## Resultados obtidos

Por exemplo, acabei de executar o novo teste do Marcelo no IE e no Chrome. Veja o gráfico resultante no momento que que escrevo:

[image: Velocidade do teste nos diferentes navegadores]

O item referente ao **IE 10.0** fui eu quem acabei de rodar. O navegador parece abstrair os cálculos de forma que o resultado é uniforme em todos os testes. Chega a ser estranho.

Já os resultados no Chrome mostraram que a multiplicação de inteiros foi excepcionalmente mais rápida. Porém, a multiplicação por ponto flutuante foi pior que a divisão simples.

Os demais navegadores não mostraram diferenças significativas.

Com exceção do Safari versão 4, **na maioria dos testes, a premissa do artigo citado na pergunta foi provada ser falsa**, isto é, a operação `4 * .5` não foi executada mais rapidamente que `4 / 2`.

## Análise

Quanto às diferenças entre os navegadores, isso certamente depende da forma como a divisão é implementada em cada *engine*. Teríamos que analisar o tipo usado na linguagem original e as conversões realizadas internamente nessa linguagem, para então analisar o consumo de CPU.

Em linguagens de mais baixo nível, a divisão pode ser uma operação mais cara, porém em uma execução linear provavelmente não veríamos diferença, já que os processadores matemáticos podem finalizar a operação em apenas um ciclo. Talvez haja uma diferença em processadores com *Hyper-threading*, que acumulam mais de uma operação por ciclo quando há operações mais "leves" como multiplicação de inteiros, mas não conseguiriam fazê-lo com operações mais "complexas". Note que *não tenho conhecimento profundo sobre processadores para afirmar com absoluta certeza*, além do mais isso depende da própria estrutura da CPU e pode ser verdade apenas em casos específicos.

### Conclusão

**A afirmação de que "multiplicação é mais rápido que divisão" mostrou-se ser falsa em muitos casos.** Ela foi verdadeira para multiplicação de inteiros em alguns navegadores, mas não para ponto flutuante como forma de substituir a divisão.

A não ser que você esteja trabalhando em um dispositivo embarcado com memória e processamento extremamente limitados, não perca tempo com esse tipo de micro otimização, ainda mais em uma linguagem como Javascript que roda em diferentes *engines*, sistemas operacionais e processadores.

Comment: Tenta realizar de novo com números feios, como números primos de 5 algarismos. (Só pra ver)

Comment: @GustavoMaciel Refiz usando o número 65537 e não houve diferença. Na verdade, numa das execuções no FF, a divisão com ponto flutuante foi ligeiramente mais lenta, mas nada muito discrepante das demais, o que me sugere que foi uma desvantagem circunstancial. A divisão usando números inteiros obteve resultado igual ao das multiplicações.

Comment: Eu pedi só por motivos científicos hehe, além do mais, divisão por dois por inteiro seria otimizado como um shift right, que poderia causar diferenças nos resultados.

Comment: Eu [refiz os testes](http://jsperf.com/multiply-vs-divide-fight/4) usando uma gama maior de valores, mais umas coisinhas para evitar "confounding" (para referência, sugiro [esse artigo do Zed Shawn](http://zedshaw.com/essays/programmer_stats.html) [em inglês] sobre programação e estatística), e tive resultados... bem, nada consistentes (entre diferentes browsers). Mas a multiplicação inteira de fato apresentou uma performance mais elevada que as demais, sobretudo no Chrome. Se possível, gostaria que mais pessoas testassem em diferentes ambientes, para agregar mais dados.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel Concordo, e creio que se refere a um **divisor** diferente de dois, certo? Os testes existentes só variavam o dividendo... :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr Muito boa elucidação para a questão. Eu bem que fiquei desconfiado daqueles laços...

Answer (score 8):

Existem diversos algoritmos eficientes para realizar - em binário - a multiplicação (ex.: [Dadda multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_tree), [Wallace tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_tree)) e a divisão (ex.: [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division), [Goldschmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Goldschmidt_division)). Frequentemente elas [a multiplicação pelo menos] são efetuadas [diretamente na CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_ALU), o que traz resultados bastante rápidos.

> <sub>**Fonte:** [essa pergunta no Yahoo! Respostas](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100622163002AAVU0PG) (de 4 anos atrás)</sub>

Quanto à divisão, tenho dificuldade de encontrar dados concretos e atualizados, mas posso afirmar com segurança que:

1. É possível sim implementar a divisão em hardware - e isso é feito já há bastante tempo;
2. Entretanto, ela é **mais cara** (i.e. exigindo uma lógica mais complexa).

Digo isso baseado no [Bug do Pentium](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeito_de_ponto_flutuante), onde uma tentativa de otimização na divisão de pontos flutuantes (FDIV) provocou um erro em várias operações que - embora incomuns para usos do dia-a-dia - afetou de forma significativa usos mais especializados (como Astronomia, que lida rotineiramente com números muito grandes). A causa raiz do erro foi a tentativa de simplificar uma *lookup table* destinada a acelerar o processo de divisão - que de outra forma seria de fato mais lento.

(**Nota:** ao contrário do que diz o artigo da Wikipedia **em português**, o erro não foi na multiplicação, e sim na divisão. Para mais detalhes, ver [o artigo em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug))

Muito tempo se passou desde o Pentium pra cá, e a [Lei de Moore](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_de_Moore) tornou as operações matemáticas em hardware mais rápidas e baratas. Ou seja, não posso afirmar se uma é ou não mais rápida que a outra **hoje** sem fazer *benchmarks* - em diferentes linguagens e circunstâncias. Quanto a JavaScript, esse [teste no jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/multiply-vs-divide-fight/4) (adaptado da [resposta do Luiz Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11429/215)) mostrou resultados inconclusivos - variando de browser pra browser. Entretanto, a multiplicação entre números **inteiros** parece ser um pouco mais rápida que as demais operações (ou muito mais rápida, no Chrome): divisão inteira, multiplicação em ponto flutuante e divisão em ponto flutuante.

P.S. Esse teste se refere a divisão por números **arbitrários**. Quando se tenta dividir por uma constante, é comum o compilador (ou interpretador, ou compilador JIT) substituir a divisão por uma operação mais simples (shift, multiplicação pelo inverso, ou algo mais sofisticado - ver [esse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10909/por-que-multiplicacao-e-mais-rapido-que-divisao/13810#comment24195_10911)). Desse modo, não creio que os dois códigos de exemplo apresentados tenham diferença significativa de performance... mas para dizer com certeza somente verificando via experimentação.

Answer (score 6):

A seguir segue uma tabela com a latência em ciclos de clock das operações de multiplicação e divisão para comparação.

Note que, se o seu programa chegar de fato a realizar tais operações, é isto que vai ocorrer no nível do hardware e não há como escapar disto.

```
| Intel Core i7                     |
|-----------------------------------|
| Instruction | Operand   | Latency |
|-------------|-----------|---------|
| MUL/IMUL    | r8        | 3       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r16       | 5       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r32       | 5       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r64       | 3       |
| IMUL        | r16,r16   | 3       |
| IMUL        | r32,r32   | 3       |
| IMUL        | r64,r64   | 3       |
| IMUL        | r16,r16,i | 3       |
| IMUL        | r32,r32,i | 3       |
| IMUL        | r64,r64,i | 3       |
| MUL/IMUL    | m8        | 3       |
| MUL/IMUL    | m16       | 5       |
| MUL/IMUL    | m32       | 5       |
| MUL/IMUL    | m64       | 3       |
| IMUL        | r16,m16   | 3       |
| IMUL        | r32,m32   | 3       |
| IMUL        | r64,m64   | 3       |
| IMUL        | r16,m16,i |         |
| IMUL        | r32,m32,i |         |
| IMUL        | r64,m64,i |         |
| DIV         | r8        | 11-21   |
| DIV         | r16       | 17-22   |
| DIV         | r32       | 17-28   |
| DIV         | r64       | 28-90   |
| IDIV        | r8        | 10-22   |
| IDIV        | r16       | 18-23   |
| IDIV        | r32       | 17-28   |
| IDIV        | r64       | 37-100  |
| FMUL        | r         | 5       |
| FMUL        | m         |         |
| FDIV        | r         | 7-27    |
| FDIV        | m         | 7-27    |
| FIMUL       | m         | 5       |
| FIDIV       | m         | 7-27    |

| AMD Steamroller                     |
|-------------------------------------|
| Instruction | Operand     | Latency |
|-------------|-------------|---------|
| MUL/IMUL    | r8/m8       | 4       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r16/m16     | 4       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r32/m32     | 4       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r64/m64     | 6       |
| IMUL        | r16,r16/m16 | 4       |
| IMUL        | r32,r32/m32 | 4       |
| IMUL        | r64,r64/m64 | 6       |
| IMUL        | r16,(r16),i | 5       |
| IMUL        | r32,(r32),i | 4       |
| IMUL        | r64,(r64),i | 6       |
| IMUL        | r16,m16,i   |         |
| IMUL        | r32,m32,i   |         |
| IMUL        | r64,m64,i   |         |
| DIV         | r8/m8       | 17-22   |
| DIV         | r16/m16     | 15-25   |
| DIV         | r32/m32     | 13-39   |
| DIV         | r64/m64     | 13-70   |
| IDIV        | r8/m8       | 17-22   |
| IDIV        | r16/m16     | 14-25   |
| IDIV        | r32/m32     | 13-39   |
| IDIV        | r64/m64     | 13-70   |
| FMUL        | r/m         | 5       |
| FIMUL       | m           |         |
| FDIV        | r           | 9-37    |
| FDIV        | m           |         |
| FIDIV       | m           |         |

| VIA Nano L3050                    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Instruction | Operand   | Latency |
|-------------|-----------|---------|
| MUL/IMUL    | r8        | 2       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r16       | 3       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r32       | 3       |
| MUL/IMUL    | r64       | 8       |
| IMUL        | r16,r16   | 2       |
| IMUL        | r32,r32   | 2       |
| IMUL        | r64,r64   | 5       |
| IMUL        | r16,r16,i | 2       |
| IMUL        | r32,r32,i | 2       |
| IMUL        | r64,r64,i | 5       |
| DIV         | r8        | 22-24   |
| DIV         | r16       | 24-28   |
| DIV         | r32       | 22-30   |
| DIV         | r64       | 145-162 |
| IDIV        | r8        | 21-24   |
| IDIV        | r16       | 24-28   |
| IDIV        | r32       | 18-26   |
| IDIV        | r64       | 182-200 |
| FMUL        | r/m       | 4       |
| FDIV        | r/m       | 14-23   |
```

Fonte: [Instruction tables: Lists of instruction latencies, throughputs and micro-operation breakdowns for Intel, AMD and VIA CPUs](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manual_instr_tab)

Isto mostra que de fato o seu processador vai realizar divisões de forma mais lenta que multiplicações. Isso se deve à implementação em hardware destas operações sofrer das mesmas questões de complexidade algorítmica já discutidas em outras respostas. Independente disso, o seu programa de uma forma ou de outra, irá fazer uso destas instruções para realizar tais operações de forma eficiente, e estará limitado à performance que elas oferecem.

Quanto aos benchmarks e dicas duvidosas que supostamente se baseiam nisto, cuidado. Cada linguagem vai tratar as expressões da forma como ela define, a expressão `1/2` no fonte em C e C++ vai acabar virando uma constante `0` no executável, e não vai ser realizada nenhuma divisão durante a execução do programa, em uma linguagem dinâmica como javascript por exemplo, o custo da interpretação das duas operações pode tornar o custo das instruções aritméticas discutidas irrelevante para a análise. Isto é só um exemplo, e o programador sábio vai saber quando multiplicação vs divisão faz sentido ou não, há casos que realmente faz, algoritmos (me vem a mente [Bresenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) agora...) e linguagens onde isto faz a diferença. Quando o programador não tem noção disto, e pratica hábitos de forma religiosa, cai no caso da [micro otimização que é a raiz de todo o mal](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 3):

Bom galera, o motivo de a divisão ser mais lenta, não ta na linguagem e sim no processador.
Visto que uma operação de multiplicação o processador irá realizar uma soma binária, como exemplo no sistema decimal onde 5 x 5 = 25 sendo 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 25. Já na divisão teremos 2 operações diferentes, que é a multiplicação e a subtração, No exemplo 25 : 5, primeiro você ira realizar uma multiplicação, para depois realizar a subtração. Resumindo o processador terá que fazer mais processos envolvendo aritmética binária.

Comment: Subtração? Podes elaborar sobre esse ponto?