# Tempo de Execução de calculo módulo(%)

Tags: algoritmo

> **Declaração das variáveis:**

```
var x= 200;

var y= 50;
```

> **Módulo:**

```
var resposta = x % y;
```

> **O que o módulo deve fazer, eu acredito(calculo):**

```
s1 = x / y;
s2 = s1 * y;
resposta = s2 - x;
```

A questão em si é: O calculo que o módulo faz, leva o mesmo tempo de execução que se eu fizesse na mão?

Comment: Você pergunta para alguma linguagem específica? (seu exemplo sugere JavaScript) Em geral, diria que a resposta é **não**: esse cálculo pode ser feito no hardware, usando um algoritmo próprio e otimizado. Mas não tenho conhecimento suficiente para embasar essa afirmação. E de todo modo, linguagens diferentes podem implementar isso de formas diferentes, então é difícil responder assim no vazio.

Comment: Qualquer linguagem, usei javascript, porque acho mais simples.

Comment: P.S. [Pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10909/215). Lá se fala só sobre divisão e multiplicação (não sobre módulo, como aqui), mas como as evidências sugerem que o mesmo algoritmo (implementado na ALU por `IDIV`) produz como resultados tanto o quociente quanto o resto, creio que as considerações lá podem se aplicar também aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7424269/520779), é possível se calcular o quociente **e** o resto de uma divisão com um única operação `IDIV`. Ou seja, cada um desses 3 trechos de código:

```
// Trecho 1
var quociente = x / y;

// Trecho 2
var resto = x % y;

// Trecho 3
var quociente = x / y;
var resto = x % y;
```

poderia a princípio ser executado com apenas 1 instrução (isso mesmo: as duas instruções em código de alto nível no trecho 3 seriam traduzidas em uma única instrução de baixo nível).

Digo *poderiam*, pois não sei como é feito na prática de linguagem pra linguagem: espera-se que os compiladores sejam capazes de fazer essa conversão corretamente (talvez exceto pelo trecho 3, em que a dificuldade na otimização é maior). Mas linguagens interpretadas, linguagens com tipos de dados dinâmicos, etc podem implementar isso de outra forma. A única forma de saber com certeza seria analisando o código de baixo nível gerado (como a resposta linkada o fez, para C++).

P.S. Eu sei que "módulo" (`mod`) é diferente de "resto" (`rem`) - há circunstâncias em que eles são diferentes, em particular envolvendo números negativos - mas pra fins dessa resposta considerei-os equivalentes.

Comment: Sim.Então isso responde minha pergunta. Um cálculo com toda a certeza é mais rápido que vários.