# Até que ponto a otimização prematura é um problema?

Tags: desempenho, otimização, ciência-da-computação

**Otimização prematura** é quando há uma preocupação excessiva por parte do programador com o desempenho da aplicação.

Ela é normalmente condenada por alguns programadores por motivos como:

- Isso pode deixar o código mais complexo
- Sua produtividade cai, você perde tempo
- Há uma grande chance de você se preocupar muito com otimizações que não trarão uma melhora perceptível pelo usuário

A recomendação seria que você primeiro fizesse funcionar, e só depois identificasse os gargalos de desempenhos e os corrigisse.

Porém, há certas otimizações que devem ser levadas em conta desde o início, pois depois pode se tornar mais difícil otimizar.

Até que ponto devemos nos preocupar com o desempenho, sem que isso cause uma perda considerável na produtividade?

Comment: Relevante: http://www.xkcd.com/1319/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Uma analogia

Quando um professor exige que seus alunos façam uma determinada tarefa, qual é uma das perguntas mais importantes a ser feita?

***"Qual é o prazo de entrega?"***

A entrega pode ser imediata, para o dia seguinte ou até para o fim do semestre, não é?

Podemos usar esta analogia para entender qual o nível de otimização que devemos aplicar em uma certa funcionalidade ou mesmo em todo um software.

Os requisitos não-funcionais de um sistema devem explicitar as expectativas quanto ao desempenho de funcionalidades cruciais.

Por exemplo:

> O sistema deve suportar o acesso simultâneo de até 1000 usuários.

Ou ainda:

> O tempo de resposta não deve ultrapassar os 5 segundos para até 10 mil usuários.

Com base nessas características (que são objeto de outro estudo), acrescentando nossa experiência e talvez um protótipo, podemos então decidir quanto investir em otimização desde cedo, apesar de que neste caso não chamaria exatamente de prematura.

## Os problemas

### Micro otimizações são um equívoco

O problema principal com otimizações que são prematuras é quando o desenvolvedor supõe que está fazendo um código mais rápido, quando na verdade ele nem possui evidências de que isso realmente vai acontecer nos "finalmentes".

Muito já foi discutido aqui no SOpt sobre [*micro benchmarks* e diferenças pequenas entre comandos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10909/por-que-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-mais-r%C3%A1pido-que-divis%C3%A3o), só para citar um exemplo. No link citado, afirma-se que multiplicação é mais rápido que divisão em Javascript. Se alguém tomar isso por verdade sempre, vai acabar percebendo que, na verdade, em alguns navegadores o oposto pode ser verdade, dependendo de algumas circunstâncias.

E ainda nem começamos a falar sobre interpretadores, JITs, *cache* e outros mecanismos dinâmicos de otimização que interferem em tudo isso.

Portanto, praticamente toda micro otimização é fadada ao fracasso, cedo ou tarde, já que se algo pode ser feito de forma *automática*, então isso pode ser *automatizado* na próxima versão do compilador ou interpretador.

Por outro lado, ainda na linha de Javascript, existem projetos que demandam alto desempenho. Um exemplo é o [tracking.js](http://trackingjs.com/), que implementa visão computacional em tempo real, onde cada ciclo de processamento conta.

Em casos como esse, essas micro otimizações são bem-vindas, porém dificilmente isso é alcançado já num primeiro desenvolvimento, ao contrário, testes práticos irão mostrar quais otimizações na verdade afetam positivamente o desempenho.

## Requisitos mudam

Além disso, como todos sabemos, requisitos são extremamente mutáveis, tanto quanto a opinião do usuário final do sistema.

Então, outro grande problema é que otimizações prematuras jogam no lixo o tempo investido e, consequentemente, o dinheiro.

## Efeito real

Outro ponto é que muitas das otimizações prematuras são praticamente inúteis. Por exemplo, usar um campo `byte` ao invés de `int` no banco de dados pode parecer uma "otimização" interessante durante o início da modelagem, mas no fim das contas, se o sistema fizer um `select *` o ganho será praticamente nulo.

Se aplicarmos aqui o Princípio de Pareto, diríamos que 80% dos problemas de desempenho devem estar em no máximo 20% do código. Isso significa que, muito provavelmente, poderíamos atingir o desempenho adequado para um sistema comum focando apenas nas funcionalidades prioritárias. E então chegamos num ponto onde o esforço para melhorar chega a ser tão grande que simplesmente não vale a pena.

## Conclusão

Temos de evitar rótulos.

Otimização são sempre bem-vindas quando sabemos o que estamos fazendo e temos um motivo para isso.

Poderia dizer que uma *otimização prematura* é uma *otimização impensada* ou ainda uma *otimização desnecessária*, que traz mais prejuízo do que ganho.

Então, respondendo finalmente á pergunta principal de forma geral, uma otimização passa a ser ruim quando ela atrapalha mais do que ajuda.

Comment: +1 Excelente explicação, muito didática

Comment: Concordo com os pontos levantados... no ambiente de trabalho. Para quem vê programação como um hobby (o/) micro-otimizações são um excelente meio de conhecer detalhes da linguagem. Tem ainda àqueles que tem conhecimento sobre determinadas micro-otimizações e já as usam há tanto tempo que durante a codificação, seja sob pressão ou não, que elas "saem" automaticamente. Por exemplo, em PHP incrementar um contador com += é muito ligeiramente mais eficiente do que com ++. Mas faço isso há tanto tempo que nem penso.

Comment: Parei aqui através de um vídeo do YouTube falando sobre 5 dicas de otimização do Yoda do vale do silicio e o segundo item se tratava disso, porém acabou não sendo claro, acredito que sua resposta clareia bem o que o Filipe quis dizer no vídeo. Segue o link para quem tiver curiosidade https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGfSYDDhouk

Answer (score 22):

Primeiro vamos entender de onde veio o termo "otimização prematura:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth

Você pode ver a [citação na Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29) (e veja que a origem é na verdade do Tony Hoare).

Eu vou dizer que citação pela metade é a raiz de todo o mal :P

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil

Veja o [artigo na na Wikipedia sobre otimização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Otimização prematura significa apenas que você não deve perseguir pequenos ganhos e principalmente ganhos incertos. E ganhos incertos é o que mais existe. As pessoas supõem algum comportamento e programam em cima desta suposição. O que você está otimizando possivelmente está criando um gargalo em outro lugar onde a otimização seria mais útil.

De acordo com a citação, 3% do tempo você deve otimizar (mesmo para pequenos ganhos). Ok, este número pode ser meio chutado, mas convenhamos que não é um número desprezível. Se a otimização é necessária ela deve ser feita. E feita por quem sabe como alcançar o resultado desejado. Você **pode** gastar tempo otimizando código, pode deixar o código complexo para obter os ganhos de performance, desde que sejam absolutamente necessários.

A preocupação com o exagero na tentativa de otimização é mais com a ineficácia da ação do que com a produtividade, embora esta possa ser uma preocupação legítima também. Está relacionado um pouco a não tornar o código complexo e "sujo" **desnecessariamente**, mas porque isto pode se voltar contra o objetivo.

A parte ruim desta citação é que ela acabou por se transformar em "nunca otimize" e vemos softwares sem nenhuma preocupação com performance.

## Os erros cometidos

- Design correto é útil e importante

  Muitos programadores não se preocupam em aprender sequer a identificar [complexidade de algoritmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) e entender a [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ([tabela de complexidades](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/)) e criam rotinas exponenciais por acidente ou abusam dos algoritmos lineares quando um logaritmo ou constante são facilmente obtidos. Ou ainda não entendem que constante O(1) nem sempre significa mais rápido. Muitas vezes o programador até sabe um pouco sobre o assunto mas faz suposições que se mostram falsas na prática. Um dos perigos de entender muito deste assunto (claro que a solução não é ignorá-los) é se apaixonar pela teoria. E é nesta hora que a otimização prematura ocorrerá. Falo mais deste assunto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33330/101).

  É importante entender o problema e dar soluções reais de otimização onde é necessário o mais cedo possível quando você sabe com base em dados realistas que ela será necessária. Só a experiência qualificada permite fazer isto com competência. Mesmo assim é algo difícil, mesmo os melhores programadores vão ter dificuldade em identificar os gargalos cedo. Então a estratégia é não se apegar à otimização como se ela fosse a coisa mais importante a fazer. Entender que em determinado momento é melhor deixar para depois e deixar possibilidades que permitam e facilitam isto. É necessário evitar um *design* que dificulte a otimização posterior. Mas tenha em mente que resolver problema de performance depois é mais difícil do que resolver antes.

  Outro erro comum que não deixa de ser de *design* é na escolha da linguagem ou tecnologia adotada. Na maioria das vezes isto não importa para a performance mas há casos que a escolha correta é fundamental. Achar que fazer em Assembly garante o melhor resultado é tão bobo quanto achar que tudo pode ser feito em Ruby impunemente.

  O *design* envolve a parte estratégica e tática da aplicação. Envolve a arquitetura, escolha das tecnologias, estruturas de dados e algoritmos utilizados.
- Não estamos mais evoluindo em poder computacional do processador como ocorria antes. Não podemos mais contar que a evolução consertará certos problemas de performance.
- Gastar o tempo do usuário normalmente custa mais que o gasto adicional para fazer boas otimizações. Ter um produto com performance ruim é mais caro que desenvolver a otimização. Performance é *feature* e não *bug*. Parece óbvio mas muitos programadores aprenderam que otimizar é criar código errado, *bugado*.
- Micro-otimização é ruim.

  Nas outras respostas fica bem óbvio onde não se deve otimizar: **não faça micro-otimizações**. Muitas vezes isto é usado como desculpa para não otimizar onde deve. Elas podem ser feitas se forem necessárias, obtenham ganhos mensurados e não prejudiquem o código.

  Isso não significa optar por qualquer forma. Se você tem duas formas "limpas" de fazer, não há desvantagens, e uma delas é realmente mais rápida que a outra, não existe razão para optar pela mais lenta.

  Um dos erros que vejo nessas avaliações é que o programador não se preocupa com um ganho pequeno em um método inofensivo, e em geral não é para preocupar-se exageradamente mesmo, mas ele esquece que aquele método será usado em um algoritmo com um problema exponencial que executará trilhões de vezes. Avaliou bem o micro e esqueceu do macro. Nesse caso a solução macro passa pela solução micro. **Pequenas otimizações são muito úteis quando se sabe onde e porquê**.

  Na maioria das vezes uma micro-otimização deve vir depois da verificação e avaliação correta que ela é necessária. Esta é a parte operacional do desenvolvimento.

  Reinventar a roda costuma ser micro-otimização. A não ser quando não é :)

## Conclusão

Preocupar-se com otimização é algo **bom**, até mesmo a otimização antecipada. Preocupar-se exageradamente, ficar obcecado, não saber onde otimizar, onde investir seu tempo, não saber priorizar, não entender o problema, não ter comprometimento é algo **ruim**.

Falta conhecimento aos programadores para evitar que as otimizações venham por acidente, assim como uma otimização teórica se transforme em prejuízo.

Otimização esperada é diferente de otimização prematura. Se todo mundo entende uma construção otimizada (com resultados reais) isto não pode ser considerado otimização prematura. Há muito preciosismo nestes discursos pró código limpo (não entenda errado, código limpo é algo bom, faço isto antes de existirem livros sobre o assunto).

Fontes:

- [THE FALLACY OF PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451) (é realmente um texto muito bom que eu concordo 100%)
- [The ‘premature optimization is evil’ myth](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Legal, porque só ter respostas que concordam entre si é a raiz de todo mal.

Comment: @bfavaretto curiosamente eu concordo com tudo das outras respostas :) Só dei uma outra abordagem colocando um outro lado, mas a resposta não antagoniza com as outras.

Comment: Ela discorda concordando :)

Answer (score 7):

Existe um princípio chamado **YAGNI** - You Ain't Gonna Need It ( Você não vai precisar disso ) que trata sobre isso.

Temos de nos preocupar com performance e recursos sempre, com boas práticas. Mas quanto ao nível de otimização que se irá fazer vai depender muito do objetivo do código.

Supondo que você esteja criando uma API para acesso externo e tem um método que será chamado em média 1 vez por dia por cliente, como um ChecarPorAtualizações. E também um outro que é chamado diversas vezes, como uma autenticação.

O método de checar por atualizações não precisa de muito esforço, já o de autenticação, não seria bom que demorasse muito.

Ainda assim, antecipar performance de algo previsto que necessitará é válido, imaginar que se, algum cliente, num certo dia, resolver checar por atualizações a cada 100ms pode deixar o sistema lento, daí acredito que não.