# Forma mais eficiente de usar "expression" em ciclos "for" aprimorados

Tags: java, desempenho

Dentre as formas seguintes, qual a mais eficiente?

```
...
//assumindo que o método pegaListaPessoas() pesquisa na base de dados todos as pessoas
for (Pessoa pAux : pegaListaPessoas())
{
    //executo alguma coisa
}
```

ou:

```
...
//assumindo que o método pegaListaPessoas() pesquisa na base de dados todos as pessoas
List<Pessoa> pessoas = pegaListaPessoas();
for (Pessoa pAux : pessoas)
{
    //executo alguma coisa
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sempre a melhor forma de você descobrir isto é medir. O que pode parecer uma coisa na teoria, pode se mostrar outra em um caso específico real. Na verdade isto pode ser considerado [otimização prematura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30277/101).

Se você pergunta para pessoas aleatórias na internet que não conhecem uma implementação, as condições exatas da sua aplicação e os requisitos de performance, não espere algo muito preciso.

Eu não posso responder com absoluta certeza porque não conheço a implementação do `pegaListaPessoas()`, não sei a implementação do que ele retorna até porque sequer sei o que ele retorna. Mas poderia **chutar** com boa chance de acerto que não faz diferença.

O que este método retorna? Um [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) que varre uma lista cacheada do conteúdo do banco de dados? E a implementação desta interface é um `List`? Ou é uma implementação própria onde o `next()` vai consultar o banco de dados? Se existir um problema de performance, ele pode estar em um lugar diferente do imaginado.

A grosso modo as implementações devem ser compilados para o equivalente a

```
for (Iterator<Pessoa> i = pegaListaPessoas().iterator(); i.hasNext(); i.next()) {
```

e

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = pegaListaPessoas();
for (Iterator<Pessoa> i = pessoas.iterator(); i.hasNext(); i.next()) {
```

No primeiro caso, ele chama o `pegaListaPessoas()` **na primeira vez**, recebe um `iterator` da lista criada pelo método, tudo isto antes do primeiro `;` e a cada passo ele vai pegar o próximo item da iteração com o `next()` (após o segundo `;`) e verificar se existe mais algum item com o `hasNext()`. Somente estes dois últimos são executados em cada passo. A inicialização é executada apenas uma vez.

A única diferença no segundo caso é que a lista é gerada antes de iniciar o *loop*.

Na verdade se você visualizar isto como um `while` fica mais óbvio:

```
Iterator<Pessoa> i = pegaListaPessoas().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()){
     Pessoa p = i.next();
}
```

e

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = pegaListaPessoas();
Iterator<Pessoa> i = pessoas.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
     Pessoa p = i.next();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Iterations.java).

Entendeu que o segredo é o `iterator`? E até onde eu sei um *loop* `for in` só pode executar em cima de coleções que implementam a interface `Iterable` (talvez com exceção de um `array`, `String` e outros tipos que a linguagem tenha ciência do funcionamento e use o índice diretamente).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown pela pronta resposta a minha questão. Li atentamente a sua resposta e compreendo o seu ponto. Mas achei que algumas questões, embora corretas não fazem parte daquilo que é o escopo da minha questão, creio que seria algo muito mais simples.

Comment: @ColdHack Então torne a questão mais clara.

Comment: Desculpa lá @bigown, estava a editar o meu comentário e depois observei que excedi o limite de carateres.Uma forma mais simples(pra mim) de perceber seria:
- No primeiro caso o método "pegsListaPessoas" é sempre executado a cada interação?
Porque senão for executado em cada interação, e implicitamente é criada uma referência temporária a lista retornada, então as duas formas seriam muito semelhantes , creio.

Por outra, a implementação do método "pegaListaPessoas()" acaba por não ser o mais importante nesta análise (na minha opinião), e nos comentários sugeri que pegava da BD (exemplo apenas).

Comment: @ColdHack E foi exatamente o que eu escrevi. Você está achando que o problema é que lhe dei mais detalhes?

Comment: Mais uma vez fico agradecido pela doce explanação. E não disse que os detalhes são um problema, mas sim, a análise sobre a implementação do método que retorna a lista. Tanto que reconheci e disse que compreendi o seu ponto. Quanto ao exemplo ilustre, foi apenas para lhe mostrar como a questão poderia ser percebida (e de facto foi assim que também percebeu).

Em suma, ambas podem teoricamente (digo isso porque nunca comparei na prática) consumir os mesmos recursos e levar o mesmo tempo de execução.

Obrigado pela atenção @bigown e pelas respostas detalhadas.

Comment: @ColdHack infelizmente não estou entendendo onde você quer chegar.

Comment: @ColdHack A inicialização do `for` é executada apenas uma vez, caso essa dúvida ainda permaneça.

Comment: Após a exposição do caríssimo <<bigown>>, isto ficou claríssimo. Só pensei que alguém que ainda poderiam haver outros factores que diferenciassem as duas formas. Muito obrigado @bfavaretto