# Onde criar macros em C?

Tags: c, c++, macro

Em termos de boas práticas de programação, se eu quero criar uma macro, por exemplo, uma macro que tenha mais ou menos umas 30 linhas de códigos, devo implementar ela no arquivo `.c` ou no `.h`? Qual é a boa prática?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em termos de boas práticas você deve fazer o que é certo para cada situação. Para isso você precisa adquirir experiência. E não tem nada pior para adquirir experiência que ler "manuais" que dizem o que é certo ou errado fazer porque eles dão receitas de bolo e não ensinam.

Dito isto, macros devem ser evitadas tanto quanto possível. Nos compiladores atuais raramente elas precisam ser criadas. E se uma macro tem 30 linhas certamente tem algo errado nela. Crie uma função e ponto. Hoje eu acho que tem pouco caso de uso de macro, mesmo para uma linha, o motivo que ainda dão eu não gosto.

Pra que a macro no lugar da função? Para ter mais performance? Pode ser que fique até pior. Os compiladores otimizam as funções e elas são "linearizadas" como ocorreria com a macro, se for realmente viável (e o compilador sabe disto melhor que o programador em quase todas situações), com inúmeras vantagens em relação à macro.

Mas se quer insistir no erro, em tese nada importa onde você coloca. Apenas o padrão é que você deve usar arquivos com extensão `.h` para incluir em outros arquivos. E como o fonte da macro precisa estar disponível quando o código que a usa é compilado, é melhor incluir um um arquivo *header*. Alias, esta é mais uma desvantagem da macro.

Em C++ macros são absolutamente desnecessárias, ainda que algumas pessoas usem. Em C ainda tem alguns raros casos onde elas são interessantes, mas não para substituir códigos complexos que deveriam estar em uma função.

No SO já foi mostrado [alguns problemas da macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9104568/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas se eu tenho um bloco de código que vai ser chamado pelo sistema constantemente, não seria útil, neste caso usar macro?

Comment: Quase certamente não. E se for útil, o compilador saberá quando fazer isto melhor que você. Neste caso é quase certo que você aumentará o tamanho do código gerado à toa, isto pode trazer problemas de performance (apesar de pequeno) e o ganho será ínfimo... em teoria. Na prática o saldo pode ser negativo.

Comment: Mas macro, é carregada juntamente com o programa, o que torna sua chamada mais rápida. Enfim, ainda não estou convencido que é melhor usar funções do que macros nestas situações rsrs, se puder dar um exemplo prático.

Comment: Então use, o problema será seu. Você está tentando fazer micro-otimização. o que quase sempre ou traz resultado contrário ou um resultado melhor tão pequeno que não compensa o esforço. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101

Comment: Se sua pergunta é para um caso real e você não está convencido com a explicação acima, sugiro que você faça um benchmark, comparando as duas soluções e poste aqui um comparativo. Dificilmente você encontrará alguma diferença significativa, já que como @bigown disse, o compilador já faz otimizações. Contexto é a palavra chave: se vc quer um código tão otimizado, para uma situação tão específica, você pode recorrer ao Assembly. Como isso é exceção, na minha opinião, deve-se sempre optar pelo código mais claro, mesmo que haja algum (muitas vezes não comprovado) prejuízo de desempenho.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro ponto: evita o uso de macros como funções, faz funções reais.

Segundo ponto: em geral as macros devem ser criadas nos ficheiros de cabeçalho já que definem identificadores a serem usados por componentes externos.

Mas no teu caso não me parece que seja isso o pretendido. Apenas pretendes criar uma macro "interna", que não é para ser usada por outros ficheiros de código que fazem uso das tuas funções.

Podes meter a macro num ficheiro de extensão ".c", ou num ficheiro privado de extensão ".h".

```
#include "header.h"         // contem coisas publicas
#include "header-private.h" // contem coisas privadas
```

---

Se optares pela solução de funções reais e quiseres fazê-las privadas ... não metas o protótipo dessas funções no ficheiro de cabeçalho e define-as com `static`

```
static int private_big_function(int x) { return x + 42; }
```

Comment: Porque devo evitar?

Comment: Porque as macros de funções trazem mais problemas do que os problemas que resolvem.

Comment: Que tipo de problemas?

Comment: Principalmente problemas de interpretação de código quando for preciso alterar a "função" mais tarde. Uma macro de 35 linhas é **muito** mais dificil de entender que uma função (com espaçamento apropriado, com comentários) com 100 linhas.