# O que faz o operador # antes de um parâmetro na definição de uma macro?

Tags: c, c++, sintaxe, macro, preprocessador

Uma das possíveis definições da macro `assert()`, como encontrei no código do MinGW, é a seguinte.

```c
#define assert(_Expression) \
 (void) \
 ((!!(_Expression)) || \
  (_assert(#_Expression,__FILE__,__LINE__),0))
```

Não entendo o que o trecho `#_Expression` na quarta linha faz. Como funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trata-se de um operador de pré-processamento conhecido formalmente como "Stringification Operator" ou "Operador de Stringficação".

É usado no corpo de uma macro com o propósito de informar ao pré-processador que o parametro da macro deve ser convertido em uma string.

Basicamente, o pré-processador colocará o parâmetro da macro entre aspas duplas após ser substituído no corpo da macro.

Segue um exemplo prático como demonstração:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define debug_ptr(x)     printf("%s => %p\n", #x, x )
#define debug_int(x)     printf("%s => %d\n", #x, x )
#define debug_bool(x)    printf("%s => %s\n", #x, (x) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" )

int foobar(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 123;
    int b = 321;

    debug_ptr(&a);
    debug_int(b);
    debug_bool(a > b);
    debug_int(foobar(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Após a etapa de pré-processamento, os macros do código seriam expandidos para algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foobar(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 123;
    int b = 321;

    printf("%s => %p\n", "&a", &a )
    printf("%s => %d\n", "b", b )
    printf("%s => %s\n", "a > b", (a > b) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" )
    printf("%s => %d\n", "foobar(a)", foobar(a) )

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
&a => 0x7ffee3284a98
b => 321
a > b => FALSE
foobar(a) => 246
```

Answer (score 3):

Ele é uma espécie de `toString()` da [macro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75075/101). Ele pega aquele conteúdo e o transforma em uma *string*, portanto ele coloca aspas ali naquela expressão.

Então vamos dizer que você chama a função (macro) da pergunta assim:

```
assert(x == 0);
```

Depois de pré-processador o código ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
(void)((!!(x == 0)) || (_assert("x == 0", __FILE__, __LINE__), 0))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Stringfy.c).

Desta forma lá na função `_assert()` poderá usar com a mensagem exata da expressão que você usou no código para imprimir ou *logar* alguma informação.

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).