# Forma mais performática de retornar dados à View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, desempenho

Em uma *view* onde retornamos uma lista de objetos, e precisamos demonstrar a quantidade, como um pequeno relatório, usando algumas condições.

**Qual a forma mais performática de retornar dados à *view*?**

Explicando melhor.

Ao retornarmos uma lista objetos à *view*, por exemplo:

Utilizando o [exemplo da Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC5-Demo-with-Entity-c6bc81df), temos:

```
public class Movie 
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; } 
    public string Genre { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
}
```

E retornamos todos os `Movies` cadastrados em nosso *controller*, por exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
        { 
            return View(db.Movies.ToList()); 
        }
```

Neste caso, digamos que queremos saber a quantidade de filmes e mostrar em uma tabela, poderíamos trazer em uma `ViewBag` assim:

```
  public ActionResult Index() 
        { 
            var filmes = db.Movies.ToList();
            ViewBag.TotoalFilmes = filmes.Count();
            return View(filmes); 
        }
```

E na *view* apenas mostrar a `ViewBag`, dessa forma:

```
<p> Total: @ViewBag.TotalFilmes</p>
```

Essa é uma forma de se fazer, porém outra seria simplesmente usando o `Count()` diretamente na *view*, assim:

```
<p> Total: @Model.Count</p>
```

Daí vem a minha pergunta: **Qual das duas formas é "melhor" (mais performática)?**

Lembrando, que no exemplo eu apenas mostrei com UMA `ViewBag`. Mas gostaria de saber se tivermos diversos dados.

Caso tenha uma terceira forma, que seja melhor, ficarei feliz em conhecer também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essencialmente não faz diferença. Pode, e eu disse apenas que pode, haver uma pequena diferença entre uma ou outro, mas será irrelevante, principalmente perto do todo que será executado.

Será difícil medir confiavelmente e só medições podem dizer o que é mais rápido de fato. Eu acho que não vai dar diferença alguma. Certamente nada que seja perceptível.

Se você estiver tendo problemas de performance não será por isto, se não estiver tendo problemas é uma [micro otimização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101) inútil. Faça o que faz mais sentido para o código, o que é mais legível para você, o que é melhor manutibilidade.

Em alguma situação, onde está o código pode ser relevante, mas não nesta nem na maioria delas. Mesmo essa relevância não é tão forte assim. E se ela for importante, provavelmente você tem algum problema bem maior no código.

Eu tenho minhas dúvidas se funcionaria exatamente como você colocou, mas isso não é relevante para a pergunta.

Comment: Não estou enfrentando problemas, era mais para conhecimento. Pois vejo em artigos e em códigos aqui na empresa das duas formas (bom, pelo menos aqui funcionou, kkkkkkkk). Daí me veio essa dúvida. Se não tem uma diferença "significativa", irei fazer igual você mencionou, ver onde fica melhor para o código. Obrigado pela resposta.