# Manipulação de Vectors em C++

Tags: c++, vector

Tem algum problema se eu percorrer um `vector` pegando o tamanho dele com *vector.size()* e depois fazer um *for* sobre o vetor?

Estou fazendo esta pergunta pois quase sempre que vejo manipulação de *vectors*, usa-se um *iterator* para percorrê-lo e pegar seus respectivos valores, e eu, por ser um iniciante, não compreendo a diferença (vantagens e desvantagens) entre um e outro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Especificamente para o tipo `vector` iterar com `for` normal controlando o acesso é mais rápido que através de um iterador, mas isso não é verdade na maioria das outras coleções de dados existentes. Tem que medir.

Para acessar o elemento pelo índice, a coleção precisa ter uma forma de fazer isso, ela pode não ter, ou pode ser lenta, aí só o iterador funcionará ou funcionará melhor. O `vector` obviamente consegue acessar o índice e é bem rápido.

O principal motivo para usar um iterador é dar melhor abstração, demonstrar no código que não está apenas acessando elementos pelo seu índice e sim percorrendo ele do começo ao fim ou ao contrário. Então o iterador, num `vector`, pode ser preferido por ser mais legível, ou pelo menos mais conciso. Também ajuda o fato que se em outros casos é melhor usar iterador, porque só nesses deixará de usar? Padronize.

Vai que um dia precise mudar de `vector` para outra coleção, se escrever o código de forma adequada, poucas mudanças já resolvem o problema de forma prática. Se escrever o `for` normal e a nova coleção que substituirá o `vector` não se der bem com esta forma, ou terá que modificar coisas, ou pior, não precisará modificar nada, mas o resultado será o mesmo, terá compromissos (performance por exemplo) diferentes.

Você pode assumir coisas no `for` normal que podem não ser verdade. Por exemplo, é comum usar um `int` para incrementar o índice. Será que é o mais adequado? Quando você escolhe o mais concreto, tem que tomar uma série de cuidados. Claro que escolher o abstrato precisa de outros. No concreto precisa saber mais sobre a coleção usada. O que pode ser bom em alguns cenários, apesar de ser pior na maioria. Tem que usar o que for mais adequado em cada situação. Muitas vezes o concreto pode ser considerado [otimização prematura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101).

Claro que o acesso pelo índice permite "varrer" o `vector` de formas menos usuais, embora dê para ter algum controle sobre o iterador também.

O iterador pode dar um pouco de segurança ou criar um problema, dependerá do que será feito no corpo. Tem operações que não serão possíveis de forma natural usando um iterador, mas elas podem ser possíveis se modificar algumas coisas, como por exemplo usar uma referência. Algumas operações que podem ser desastrosas ou pelo menos prejudiciais podem ser feitas sem o programador perceber, por exemplo incrementar o iterador pode criar um novo iterador temporário que é mais lento que o normal.

O iterador pode ser mais curto:

```
for (auto& elemento: vetor)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/For.cpp).

Alguns preferem usar até mesmo funções prontas para iterar de forma mais abstrata ainda. A [`std::algorithms`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) é seu amigo. Quanto mais abstrato mais tende ter menos *bugs*.