# Quais as diferenças em questão de performance ao utilizar queries com EF vs ADO?

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, ado.net

Qual é a diferença em relação a performance ao utilizar os métodos de consulta a base `SqlQuery<TElement>` e `ExecuteSqlCommand` do *EntityFramework* em relação a utilizar diretamente o *ADO.NET*?

Caso haja diferença considerável em performance, esta é devido ao processamento de dados realizado na aplicação pelo Entity Framework antes de acessar o banco de dados ou o Entity Framework também causa impactos no banco de dados?

#### Utilizando ADO.NET para realizar um `select`:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", connection))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ///...
        }
    }
}
```

#### Utilizando Entity Framework para realizar um `select` com `SQLQuery()`:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<Table>("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
```

#### Utilizando ADO.NET para realizar um *statement* de `insert`:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('foo', 'ba', GETDATE())", connection))
    {
        int records = command.ExecuteNonQuery();        
    }
}
```

#### Utilizando Entity Framework para realizar um *statement* de `insert` com `ExecuteSqlCommand()`:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('foo', 'ba', GETDATE())");
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma [comparação antiga](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) mostrado a performance de alguns ORMs com o acesso bruto. O Entity Framework [melhorou muito](http://ppanyukov.github.io/2015/05/20/entity-framework-7-performance.html) de lá pra cá, especialmente o EF Core, mas ainda há um *overhead* natural nele. [Mais um *benchmark*](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/).

Obviamente que estas comparações dependem muito do que está sendo realizado, qual a estratégia e as configurações específicas estão sendo usadas. Ainda que todo mundo queira uma informação mágica sobre qual é mais rápido, não dá para afirmar nada sobre performance sem fazer testes específicos em situação real.

A maneira usada no código de EF é pouco usual, no fundo quase não está usando o que o EF tem a oferecer, não usa ele como um ORM completo, o que pode ser uma boa e equalizar a performance. Com estratégias iguais não haverá muita diferença de performance, pelo menos para montar a *query* que é um dos custos que pesam na performance.

Quando você opta por escrever suas próprias *queries* SQL serão elas que determinarão o grosso da performance. É muito comum o programador conseguir escrever *queries* melhores que um ORM pode escrever partindo de uma expressão C#. Novamente, vai variar de caso pra caso.

Para quem optar pelo EF, uma estratégia de otimização certamente é abandonar sua sintaxe normal que abstrai o SQL e usar uma *query* própria. Claro que esta situação pode impedir uma das vantagens do ORM que é permitir a abstração do banco de dados (algo que em geral a pessoa não precisa mas ela faz generalização prematura)

Se for para usar sempre assim, provavelmente tem pouca vantagem em usar o EF, é melhor usar um ORM mais simples como o Dapper já mencionado no *link* acima ou mesmo o ADO.NET puro.

Obviamente que outras coisas podem fazer diferença dependendo do contexto aplicado. Nem sabemos como o EF está configurado para dizer alguma coisa. Mesmo sabendo ainda será difícil fazer afirmações definitivas.

Sempre vai caber a pergunta: [você está tendo problemas de performance ou só quer que seja mais rápido o que já é rápido o suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estratégia interessante (do artigo) que sugere iniciar com `Entity Framework` e depois ir otimizando com `Dapper.NET` em alguns cenários que exigem alta performance.