# Remover itens um array que contém somente 1 caracter

Tags: php

Tenho um seguinte *array*:

```
$arr = array('estrela', 'não', 'é', 'up','.','Evitem', 'estrelar',
'abobrinha', 'coisa', 'fugaz', 'de', 'interesse', 'praticamente',
'individual', 'conversa mole','.','Só', 'porque', 'é', 'engraçado',
'não','quer','dizer','que','é','importante','e', 'útil', 'para', 
'todos', '.', 'O', 'objetivo', 'do', 'recurso', 'é', 
'destacar', 'algo', 'importante','para','as', 'pessoas', 
'que', 'não', 'são', 'frequentes', 'no', 'chat', 'abusar', 
'dele', 'acaba', 'com', 'sua', 'utilidade', 'Ajam', 'como', 
'comunidade', ',', 'pense', 'no', 'que', 'é', 'realmente', 
'útil', 'para', 'todos', 'Também', 'não' ,'quer', 'dizer', 
'que', 'nada', 'edianamente', 'fútil', 'não', 'pode', 'só', 'sejam', 
'mais', 'seletivos', '.');
```

Gostaria de remover todos os itens do *array* que possui apenas 1 caracter. Por exemplo `é`, `.` , `O`, `,`,etc; sendo letra ou até mesmo algum carácter especial como `,`(virgula).

Como posso remover itens do *array* que contém somente 1 carácter dentre eles letras e caracteres especiais?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar o tamanho dos caracteres em um loop, e remover caso o valor seja um carácter.

Código:

```
<?php
    $arr = ["gato", "g", "stack", "ba", "t", "foo", "à", "é", "bar"];

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (mb_strlen($value) == 1) {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }

    print_r($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => gato
    [2] => stack
    [3] => ba
    [5] => foo
    [8] => bar
)
```

Saída com o seu array informado como entrada de dados:

```
Array
(
    [0] => estrela
    [1] => não
    [3] => up
    [5] => Evitem
    [6] => estrelar
    [7] => abobrinha
    [8] => coisa
    [9] => fugaz
    [10] => de
    [11] => interesse
    [12] => praticamente
    [13] => individual
    [14] => conversa mole
    [16] => Só
    [17] => porque
    [19] => engraçado
    [20] => não
    [21] => quer
    [22] => dizer
    [23] => que
    [25] => importante
    [27] => útil
    [28] => para
    [29] => todos
    [32] => objetivo
    [33] => do
    [34] => recurso
    [36] => destacar
    [37] => algo
    [38] => importante
    [39] => para
    [40] => as
    [41] => pessoas
    [42] => que
    [43] => não
    [44] => são
    [45] => frequentes
    [46] => no
    [47] => chat
    [48] => abusar
    [49] => dele
    [50] => acaba
    [51] => com
    [52] => sua
    [53] => utilidade
    [54] => Ajam
    [55] => como
    [56] => comunidade
    [58] => pense
    [59] => no
    [60] => que
    [62] => realmente
    [63] => útil
    [64] => para
    [65] => todos
    [66] => Também
    [67] => não
    [68] => quer
    [69] => dizer
    [70] => que
    [71] => nada
    [72] => edianamente
    [73] => fútil
    [74] => não
    [75] => pode
    [76] => só
    [77] => sejam
    [78] => mais
    [79] => seletivos
)
```

Talvez tenha que adaptar, porque vai depender da codificação que estiver usando, e outras coisas também pode influenciar nos resultados, mas já ajuda um pouco você.

Veja funcionando [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6b7ef89cbde678abca10e01b455294616a04d8d).

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde. É só iterar o array e checar cada um dos valores pela função strlen, que retorna o tamanho da string. Caso ela retorne 1, você pode remover o elemento e trocalo por uma string vazia, ou o quê você preferir. No código eu também utilizei a função trim() para o caso de você querer remover strings como "   é {espaço em branco}"

Veja no código abaixo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
if(strlen(trim($arr[$i])) == 1)) {
$arr[$i] = "";

 }
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado =)

Comment: @AckLay sem problema =)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php).

Exemplo de uso:

```
$filtrado = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    if(strlen($item) <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Porquê `strlen($item) <= 0` ? Tem como explicar melhor?

Comment: Foi um erro de digitação. Deveria ser ```<= 1```. Editei a resposta para ficar de acordo.

Comment: Acho que sua abordagem é boa, mas ainda dá para otimizar.

Comment: A função array_filter é escrita em C, somente a sua função de callback é php. Não consigo ver uma forma de otimizar mais este código.

Comment: Por exemplo, se isso `strlen($item) <= 1` for verdadeiro ele já retorna `true`, então porque criar dois retornos? Entende o que quero dizer?

Comment: Cuidado com [microotimizações](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29507/at%c3%a9-que-ponto-a-otimiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-prematura-%c3%a9-um-problema/29519#29519)

Comment: Concordo que pode ser usado também, mas eu preferi deixar o exemplo mais simples. Não se preocupe que eu nao tenho problemas com criticas :)

Answer (score 1):

Se está preocupado com performance (*"Estou procurando algo também em questão de performance."*) não deve utilizar o `strlen()`, utilize o `empty()` ou `isset()`, em seu lugar, a diferença é minuscula, mas existe.

```
function remover_palavra_curta(string $string) : bool{
   return isset($string[1]);
}

$arr = array_filter($arr, remover_palavra_curta);
```

Em comparação, obtive este resultado, em ordem de `isset`, `strlen` e o `mb_strlen`.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.77282905578613)
  [1]=>
  float(0.81824898719788)
  [2]=>
  float(1.5776748657227)
}
```

[Utilizei este método aqui para isto](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/617e69f3736d36402e93f21a7f28e84a2d6b378d). O `0` é o `isset`, o `1` é o `strlen` e o `2` é o `mb_strlen`.

---

O `isset` e o `strlen` tem problema com o `é` por exemplo, uma vez que:

```
$texto = 'é';
var_dump( strlen($texto) === 2 );
```

Resposta, *como esperado*:

```
bool(true)
```

Isso também ocorre com o `isset()`, o `$texto[1]` também existe. Para corrigir isto apenas utilizando o `mb_strlen`, ou poderia utilizar o `ctype_alpha($texto[1])`, mas o ganho de performance seria totalmente anulado, sendo mais rápido o uso do `mb_strlen`.

---

Para ter o que quer deve abrir mão de performance e utilizar o mais lento, `mb_strlen`, ele remove todos o `é` assim como o `.`, como deseja, portanto:

```
function remover_palavra_curta(string $string) : bool{
   return mb_strlen($string) >= 2;
}
```

Comment: `mb_strlen($string) > 2` retorna valores com tamanho 2 certo?

Comment: Eu queria editar aquele meu comentário, mas ultrapassei o tempo de edição então acabei deletando. Mas é isso mesmo, em questão de performance.

Comment: Seria `>=` na verdade, mas é isso. Para que torne `true` quando for `>= 2` e `false` quando não, assim removendo o que for menor do que `2`.