# Por que uma struct deve ter no máximo 16 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, memória, objetos

Vi em uma pergunta sobre classes e estruturas que essa última deve ter no máximo 16 bytes.

Por que tem essa limitação?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade você pode usar o tamanho que quiser, a recomendação existe por uma questão de eficiência. Essa recomendação é apenas para te alertar para investigar mais se será uma boa opção se fugir de algum item desses.

Não sei se [leu aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) ou em outro lugar. Ali fala que a `struct` é sempre um tipo por valor, portanto uma instância dela é o próprio objeto. Sempre que copiar o seu valor tem que copiar o objeto, se ele for muito grande não fica muito eficiente. Um tipo por referência tem o objeto no *heap* e o que é copiado é apenas o ponteiro, no máximo 8 bytes.

Se estiver pensando se há muita cópia, há sim, toda vez que atribuir o valor há cópia, se passar ele como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) há cópia, até o uso há cópia para o registrador e possivelmente para a pilha. Claro que a cópia para registrador ou local (*stack*) é muita rápida. Se o objeto já existir a cópia no *heap* pode ser mais ou menos rápida também. Mas há custo.

Mas eu já fiz testes e vi que em determinadas arquiteturas esse limite pode ser ultrapassado. Se o *cache line* do processador for maior a performance para copiar 1, 4, 16 ou 64 bytes é praticamente a mesma, se transportar 128 bytes certamente consumirá no mínimo o dobro do tempo de 64 bytes (provavelmente mais para gerenciar a complexidade), pelo menos na maioria das arquiteturas atuais. Boa parte das arquiteturas hoje em dia usam *cache line* de 64 bytes, então todo transporte físico interno dos bits ocorre em blocos de 512. Transferir 1 ou 64 bytes dá no mesmo. Haverá um diferença para acomodar esses dados.

Claro que se a arquitetura não tem esse tipo de otimização pode dar grande diferença. Pode ser que até 16 bytes seja muito, embora a diferença não vá ser muito grande. 16 bytes costuma ir bem em todas arquiteturas e é suficiente para objetos por valor. Se usar mais que isso talvez esteja fazendo algo que já não deveria ser por valor.

Além disto pode haver alguma otimização do compilador ou [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) que ajude certos tamanhos. É bom manter em mente que isto é detalhe de implementação e pode ser que no passado 16 bytes era o recomendado, mas agora é mais. Já li que o gatilho para mudar o código gerado é 24 ou 32 bytes em 64 bits. Nunca achei informações oficiais. Não sei detalhes mas é provável que use instruções mais modernas ([SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)) que permite a cópia em bloco único. Se não usar uma instrução dessas a cópia deve ocorrer em passos, o que tornará lenta.

Se precisar de otimização extrema, se quiser evitar pressão no *garbage collector* é possível abusar um pouco deste tipo. Este site usa muito isso na sua arquitetura. Tem que saber o que está fazendo porque há uma semântica diferente em ser por valor ou referência, especialmente se o objeto for [mutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Nos casos de abusar um pouco pode-se evitar a cópia com `ref`, aí o objeto é referenciado e não copiado, como se fosse um tipo por referência. Então a cópia será de no máximo 8 bytes. Nem sempre é possível usar este tipo de artificio. Mas no C# 7 isso melhorou muito porque além de parâmetros é possível retornar um `ref` e usar em variáveis locais. E há proposta para usar `ref` em campos de um objeto, captura de *lambdas*, etc.

De qualquer forma é bom não abusar, e não fazer [otimização prematura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101). Tem que observar onde e como aquele objeto será usado, além da quantidade de instâncias que haverá.

A minha experiência é que o maior problema são os objetos de vida média (objetos que chegam na Gen1 principalmente 2 e morrem em seguida), embora alguns de vida curta demais é um desperdício ser alocado no *heap*.

Se souber o que está fazendo uma `struct` com centenas ou milhares de bytes pode ser uma boa ideia, ainda que raro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).