# Na linguagem C trabalhando com strings seria melhor gastar processamento ou memória?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, memória

Em geral na programação é melhor gastar recursos com processamento (cálculos) ou memória (criando variáveis)?

Contextualizando:

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução para um programa que utiliza `struct` e dentro dela tem alguns valores. Tenho que realizar cálculos e movimentação de *strings*, seria melhor criar variáveis dentro da `struct`, criar uma função a parte ou fazer dentro da `main()`, sei que todas as opções são validas.

Porém, qual é mais rápida, lembrando que é um vetor de `struct`?

Comment: Cuidado com as [otimizações prematuras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29507/at%C3%A9-que-ponto-a-otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-prematura-%C3%A9-um-problema)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende do que está fazendo, não é tão simples responder isso, apenas olhando cada caso poderia tomar uma decisão, e tudo depois de medir, porque nem sempre é intuitivo.

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, o processamento básico é barato, o acesso à memória é caro, muito caro, chega ser ordens de magnitude. Quanto mais evitar o acesso à memória mais rápido fica sua aplicação, por isso aplicar truques que ajudam o processador não acessar a memória principal (nem vou falar da memória de massa porque aí a diferença fica brutal) e acessar a memória própria do processador (cache), ou nem isso e conseguir fazer tudo no registrador, mais rápido fica.

Mas tem que tomar cuidado com essa coisa de criar variável gerar acesso à memória. Isso pode não acontecer, na verdade a variável pode até desaparecer na compilação se ela não for necessária. E se precisar de algo intermediário haverá um custo igual ao que tivesse criando uma variável mesmo que seu código não tenha variável alguma naquele ponto.

A intuição do programador nem sempre funciona, até mesmo quando ele tem profundo conhecimento do funcionamento do computador, sistema operacional, computação e outros elementos, imagina de quem não tem.

O mais importante é testar naquela situação, porque uma mudança pode ser que já mude tudo. E mais, pode ser que isso nem seja o motivo que fará ficar lento ou não. Quem sabe esteja alocando *string* onde não deve, ou até se precisa, se há cópia... tem tanta coisa que pode afetar mais que isso. De qualquer forma não é a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) em si que se tornará o problema é o [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101).

Agora, a pergunta é um pouco estranha quando fala em criar variáveis dentro de uma `struct` porque é a única coisa que pode criar nela.

Criar uma função à parte ou não é outra questão. Em geral eu falo que deve fazer o que é mais legível e depois pensar em performance. Mas se está fazendo coisas na `main()` deve ser algo muito simples, provavelmente não é uma preocupação real a ter.

Se puder aloque o máximo possível na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), isso é o que parece importar mais para o caso. Ou *inline* se fizer sentido (caso de uma `struct`), mas nem sempre cabe.